# Save Data in app so that it can be shown later in android studio

Tags: android, database

I am a complete newbie in android development I have started working on an app that counts the pushups. I want to save the user's history like how many pushups he did on that day his maximum pushups, pushups in the current week, and average pushups. I Don't know how to save this data so that It can be shown for future use.

Comment: please check this [room database example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example)

Comment: You can use shared preference, search about it.